# Reverse geocoding in intel XDK

Tags: geolocation, reverse-geocoding, intel-xdk

Hi I am using the following code to display the user current position on the map:

```
function drawMap() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
    myLatLng = latlng;
    var mapOptions = {
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
        },
    };
    if (boolTripTrack === true) {
        _map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    }
}


var suc = function(p) {
        console.log("geolocation success", 4);
        //Draws the map initially
        if (_map === null) {
            currentLatitude = p.coords.latitude;
            currentLongitude = p.coords.longitude;
            drawMap();
            //reverseGeocode(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
        } else {
            myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude);
        }
        //Creates a new google maps marker object for using with the pins
        if ((myLatLng.toString().localeCompare(oldLatLng.toString())) !== 0) {
            //Create a new map marker
            var Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: _map
            });
            if (_llbounds === null) {
                //Create the rectangle in geographical coordinates
                _llbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude)); //original
            } else {
                //Extends geographical coordinates rectangle to cover current position
                _llbounds.extend(myLatLng);
            }
            //Sets the viewport to contain the given bounds & triggers the "zoom_changed" event
            _map.fitBounds(_llbounds);
        }
        oldLatLng = myLatLng;
    };
var fail = function() {
        console.log("Geolocation failed. \nPlease enable GPS in Settings.", 1);
    };
var getLocation = function() {
        console.log("in getLocation", 4);
    };
```

This works fine but I need to perform reverse geocoding when a button is pressed so that the address is displayed. The function is am using is:

```
function reversegeocode(){
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(?, ?);
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[1]) {
                alert(results[1].formatted_address);
      } else {
        alert('No results found');
      }
    } else {
      alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

I am unsure of how to pass in the current latitude and longitude from the previous function. Can anyone help me with this??

Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the reverse geocode function like this, with parameters for `lat` and `lng`:

```
function reversegeocode(lat, lng){
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[1]) {
                alert(results[1].formatted_address);
      } else {
        alert('No results found');
      }
    } else {
      alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

And then call the function by passing the variables : `reverseGeocode(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);`